# Trying to emulate MacOS dropdown behavior

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to recreate the behavior of dropdowns in MacOS with Bootstrap and jQuery.  Desired behavior is show/hide on click, but also show on hover while moving between dropdowns until one is clicked again.

I have already achieved most of the desired behavior with some hastily written jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown").on("click", function(event){
        $('.dropdown').addClass('show-on-hover');
    });

    $('.nav').on('mouseenter', 'li.show-on-hover', function() {
        $('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
        $(this).addClass('open');
    });

    $('.nav').on('click', 'li.show-on-hover.open', function() {
        $('.dropdown').removeClass('show-on-hover');
    });
});
```

but I am having one issue where if I click outside of the dropdown, the others still activate on hover (which shouldn't happen, they should only re-open on click at that point).  Any suggestions on how to fix this issue, and/or suggestions for better solutions to this type of dropdown behavior would be greatly appreciated!

For instance, if this behavior can be accomplished with CSS only that would be amazing!

https://codepen.io/jakatz/pen/NjMgRg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is actually quite simple: you simply have to use a dual click-binding pattern for your desired behaviour:

1. Listen to click event on `.dropdown` and enable show-on-hover effect, but stop it from bubbling/propagating up the DOM tree, so that it does not interfere with #2. This is done by simply calling `event.stopPropagation()`
2. Listen to click event on the document, which will be used to disable the show-on-hover effect

Basically what we are doing with the logic above is that:

1. Enable show-on-hover whenever a click event is emitted from a dropdown
2. Disable show-on-hover whenever a click event is emitted anywhere else than from a dropdown

I have modified your logic and added additional logic, see proof-of-concept in the code below (you might want to view it in full screen, as the code snippet will show a mobile/narrow viewport view).

```js
$(function() {
  // Allow show on hover when dropdowns are clicked on
  $('.dropdown').on('click', function(event) {
  
    // Allow all dropdowns to show on hover
    $('.dropdown').addClass('show-on-hover');
    
    // Open menu
    $(this).toggleClass('open');
    
    // Prevent click event from bubbling up to document
    event.stopPropagation();
  });

  // Disable show on hover when click event is emitted from anywhere else
  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('show-on-hover');
  });

  // Show on hover behavior
  $('.nav').on('mouseenter', 'li.show-on-hover', function() {
    $('.dropdown.open').removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass('open');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for such a nicely written explanation!  Much appreciated.